# Make JDA Discord Bot send a random image

Tags: image, bots, discord, discord-jda

I'm currently working on a bot for my Discord server and I was wondering how to implement various **image commands** (for example, `!cat`, `!meme`) to make the bot send a random image each time the command is called.

Almost every bot I've seen has a feature like that but for some reason I can't seem to find a working way to do this in JDA. And any JDA example I found was either outdated or it simply didn't work, so I really hope someone can give me a hand here.

Here's a (very basic) example I already did, but the problem is that the pictures don't randomize with each call and just stay the same until I restart discord

```java
public void sendCatImage() {
        EmbedBuilder result= new EmbedBuilder();
        result.setTitle("Here's a cat!");
        result.setImage("http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=png");
        event.getChannel().sendMessage(result.build()).queue();
    }
```

*I'm using JDA Version 4.1.0_100, if it helps*

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord will cache the image based on the URL. You can append a random number as a query to prevent this:

```java
public String randomize(String url) {
    ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    return url + "&" + random.nextInt() + "=" + random.nextInt();
}

...
result.setImage(randomize(url));
...
```

Furthermore, you can avoid discord updating the image by also uploading it alongside the embed. For that you first need to download the image and then upload it:

```java
// Use same HTTP client that jda uses
OkHttpClient http = jda.getHttpClient();
// Make an HTTP request to download the image
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(imageUrl).build();
Response response = http.newCall(request).execute();
try {
    InputStream body = response.body().byteStream();
    result.setImage("attachment://image.png"); // Use same file name from attachment
    channel.sendMessage(result.build())
           .addFile(body, "image.png") // Specify file name as "image.png" for embed (this must be the same, its a reference which attachment belongs to which image in the embed)
           .queue(m -> response.close(), error -> { // Send message and close response when done
               response.close();
               RestAction.getDefaultFailure().accept(error);
           });
} catch (Throwable ex) {
// Something happened, close response just in case
    response.close();
// Rethrow the throwable
    if (ex instanceof Error) throw (Error) ex;
    else throw (RuntimeException) ex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I've just tried it and the images actually randomized!

However for some reason, when I click the image for a full view it shows a different image from the one in the embed. I know this will only be an inconvenience if someone actually clicks on the image, but I was wondering if there could be a way around that as well?

Comment: At `OkHttpClient http = jda.getHttpClient();` my IDE says that it cannot resolve the symbol `jda`. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA. Any advice on that?

Comment: It refers to any JDA instance, you can get one through most JDA entities with `x.getJDA()` like for example `event.getJDA()` or `channel.getJDA()`.

Comment: Ah, now it works! Thanks for taking the time to help me with this! Another problem I faced was that the `Response response = http.newCall(request).execute();` threw an unhandled `IOException`. I went around this by adding `throws IOException` to my method and then surrounding the method call with `try` and `catch`. While this fixed the issue, I'd still want to know if there is a "more correct" way of avoiding this problem.